# Typescript - Alter AST and have it work in IDE

Tags: typescript

My knowledge of compilers, AST's and TS Language Server is limited but I'll do my best to explain.

I Want Typescript and Webstorm (My IDE) to change the type of underscore in the typescript AST to treat it as a string. This is a contrived example my real use-case is a little more complicated but I'm pretty sure if I can see how to just change it to string i can work out how to go further.

I.E

```
const test = _.toString()
```

should resolve in the IDE without issues.
how can i achieve this with the typescript compiler api or any other tool?

(Note not interested in declare syntax I.E....  declare const _: string;

Iv'e had a strong search for other people doing this, and alls i can find is custom transformers but no custom AST transformations.

EDIT2: After reading Nurbols article this will not achieve what i want, it reads clearly in the first block of text that this cannot...

```
Add new custom syntax to TypeScript
Change how the compiler emits JavaScript
Customize the type system to change what is or isn't an error when running tsc
```

Comment: After reading your edit, it seems even more that you are trying to achieve weird things. What is your original problem?

Comment: Hey, Nurbol added a "EDIT2", unfortunately this will not solve my problem because i need _.toString() to not error during TSC which means i need to alter the AST

Comment: That's not original problem, though. Sorry for not being able to help you, but it's hard without understanding what you *really* try to achieve

Comment: "I Want Typescript and Webstorm (My IDE) to change the type of underscore in the typescript AST to treat it as a string."

Comment: Can you just add `declare const _: string` to the TypeScript built-in library declaration files?  That's how all the other built-in symbols (`Object`, `Array`, etc.) are declared.

Comment: its an example close to but not want i want actually, and for my real use-case i need to physically alter the AST

Answer (score 1):

You probably want Language Server Proxy/Plugin.

See this paragraph: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin#customizing-behavior

Your code should be something like (**very** roughly)

```
proxy.getCompletionsAtPosition = (fileName, position) => {
  const prior = info.languageService.getCompletionsAtPosition(fileName, position);
  prior.entries = prior.entries.concat(Object.keys(String.prototype));
  // of course you should research how to add subsequent
  // completion, i.e. give types to the newly added options
  return prior;
};
```

I hope it is helpful, but I am not giving any guarantees that you can add completion options (in the wiki article they only remove them)

Comment: Hey Nurbol iv'e read the through the example and roughly understand it, although it doesn't work in webstorm and in the related article also can't find out any webstorm support.

Comment: Ah, I Forgot about Webstorm. I guess the problem is: WebStorm is proprietary and older and Language Server Protocol is free and newer. So chances that WebStorm does not utilize LSP. I 100% recommend you to use VSCode, because the best experience you can get in VSCode is coding in Typescript and vice-versa. They are both from Microsoft and integrated very well. Moreover VSCode is free, etc. In other words VSCode all the way if you write in TypeScript

Comment: with VsCode and the guide from a plugin linked in that article (typescript-styled-plugin) and that line in my tsconfig, VsCode still doesn't intellisense.
EDIT: Not even trying the plugin from that guide, using a pre-created plugin and it doesn't intellisense

Comment: Well, I am not a VSCode maintainer nor the typescript's or plugin's, so hardly can help with this. You could answer to my question in the comment under OP, I feel there's a better solution for the original problem. BTW [LSP for JetBrains IDEs](https://github.com/gtache/intellij-lsp)